# Data type error : arr.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code in JavaScript is giving error as:

> TypeError : arr.push is not a function

```js
var arr = new Array();
arr = calc.display.value;
console.log(arr);
arr.push("*");
```

Comment: what is calc.display.value?

Comment: @AshayMandwarya Whatever it is, it's certainly not an Array.

Comment: @NikKyriakides for sure

Comment: What's the point of doing `new Array()` when the very next statement overwrites `arr` with a completely different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the variable `arr`, then overwriting it the line after.
Essentially all you do is:

```
var arr = calc.display.value;
console.log(arr);
arr.push("*");
```

You did not specify what `calc.display.value` is, assuming it's a string — all you really do is:

```
var arr = "";
console.log(arr);
arr.push("*"); //String.prototype does not contain a function called `push` thereby the error.
```

[Article on String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype)

If you want to append the string containing `calc.display.value` with "*":

```
var arr = calc.display.value;
arr += "*";
console.log(arr);
// Expected output: "displayvalue*"
```

If you want to add "*" to an array with `calc.display.value`:

```
var arr = [calc.display.value];
arr.push("*");
console.log(arr);
// Expected out: ["displayvalue", "*"]
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you are changing the type of array in this line:

```
arr = calc.display.value;
```

That's because you could not find method `push`.

Could you initialize the array like:

```
var arr = [];
//Put your element in Array
arr.push('elem1');
```